# How do I include a sum clause for two more_like_this queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

Instead of using **dis_max** in the following query, I want to find the **sum** of two `more_like_this` queries. How can I modify this query to achieve that?

```
POST /ucberkley/docs/_search
{
  "fields": [
    "Category"
  ],
  "size": 1500,
  "query": {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [{
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "PRIMARY_CONTENT_EN"
          ],
          "ids": [
            173161
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 2,
          "boost": 2
        }
      }, {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "PRIMARY_CONTENT_EN"
          ],
          "ids": [
            175277
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 2,
          "boost": -1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be  via a [bool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query using the `should` clause

Example:

```
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "disable_coord" : "true",
      "should": [{
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "PRIMARY_CONTENT_EN"
          ],
          "ids": [
            173161
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 2,
          "boost": 1
        }
      }, {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": [
            "PRIMARY_CONTENT_EN"
          ],
          "ids": [
            175277
          ],
          "min_term_freq": 1,
          "max_query_terms": 2,
          "boost": -1
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Keety. this seems to be working fine. I would get back to you with more doubts if any as currently am doing some testing on this. really appreciate your timely help. thanks.